# iOS - Interface elements overlapping when move the view

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, uitextfield

I have the following interface layout on my application:

[image]

When I click on a text field (if you lick add tag a new text field is added) I make my view scroll up as to not be obstructed by the keyboard so the user can properly see what he's typing, but the following happens when I do so:

[image][image]

This is the code I use to scroll:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {
  if (self.keyboardIsShown) {
    return;
  }

  NSValue *keyboardBoundsValue = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey];
  CGSize keyboardSize = [keyboardBoundsValue CGRectValue].size;

  NSTimeInterval animationDuration = 0.3;

  CGRect frame = self.view.frame;

  frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height - 94 + self.firstResponder.superview.superview.frame.origin.y;
  frame.size.height += keyboardSize.height - 94 + self.firstResponder.superview.superview.frame.origin.y;

  [UIView beginAnimations:@"ResizeForKeyboard" context:nil];
  [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
  self.view.frame = frame;
  [UIView commitAnimations];

  self.keyboardIsShown = YES;
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification {
  NSValue *keyboardBoundsValue = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey];
  CGSize keyboardSize = [keyboardBoundsValue CGRectValue].size;

  NSTimeInterval animationDuration = 0.3;

  CGRect frame = self.view.frame;

  frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height - 94 + self.firstResponder.superview.superview.frame.origin.y;
  frame.size.height -= keyboardSize.height - 94 + self.firstResponder.superview.superview.frame.origin.y;

  [UIView beginAnimations:@"ResizeForKeyboard" context:nil];
  [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
  self.view.frame = frame;
  [UIView commitAnimations];

  self.keyboardIsShown = NO;
}
```

Any idea how I can make the view elements show behind the navbar or disappear or another workaround that would work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick way to achieve what you want, would be to have your navigation bar below the "content"-view in your view tree. That way the navigation bar will remain on top. If you add the content dynamically. Make sure you add them as subviews of a view that is behind the navigation bar.

// Edit

As proposed in the comments:

```
self.view.clipsToBounds = YES;
CGRect frame = self.yourWrappingView.frame;
NSUInteger distanceToMove = 200;
self.yourWrappingView.frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x - distanceToMove, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
```

This should work for you mate :)

Comment: It's all created in storyboards, except the additional table view cells from the add tag.

Comment: So wrap the content that you move in a view that is inside the view controller's main view. The problem is, that you're moving the view controllers main view, you shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: Alright, and how should I do it? Have a subview like you say that wraps everything up?

Comment: So you should have a property for the wrapping view, set the viewController's main view's clipsToBounds property to YES, and move the wrapping view up.

Comment: 8vius I edited my answer to include a codesample of what I propose you do.

Comment: Alright I'll give it a shot, now, just to be clear, why is it ill advised to move the controller's view?

Comment: Because it should represents the entire screen.

Comment: Thanks for the help Rasmus, this lead me to a good solution. Instead of embedding my view in another view, I just grab what elements would move and placed them in a scroll view, and moved that.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are not using a real `UINavigationController`. But you should. So you wouldn't have those problems and a correct resizing behaviour. But to solve it in your current architecture:

- Make sure the Navigation Bar is the top most object in your nib file / storyboard
- add an IBOutlet for your UINavigationBar and if you insert new views dynamically, use `[self insertSubview: newView belowSubview: navigationBarOutlet];`

Comment: My view is embedded in the navigation controller, I'm using iOS 5.1. And only the cells for the table view are inserted dynamically.